STM32 USB DFU bootloader
Is there a USB DFU bootloader for STM32F103R8?

I checked the documentation for "USB DFU protocol used in the STM32 bootloader". The applicable products table(Table 1) shows up that STM32F1 and it's series. If I am looking at right documentation there is a bootloader for USB DFU.


According to AN2606 (STM32 microcontroller system memory boot mode) table 3, only USART is supported by F103 bootloaders. F105/F107 bootloaders do support USB DFU, so it is indeed applicable to F1 series, just not F103.
